# SQL SELECT based on one of three possible conditions in a single query

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm new to SQL.  Currently doing the second challenge of the course "CS50 Web Programming with Python and Javascript".  I'm tasked with building a book review site and on the search page the user can search via title OR author OR isbn.  I have this SQL set up at the moment but it seems a bit ugly.  My question, is there a more elegant way of achieving the same?  Ideally in a single SQL query.

```
    page = request.form.get("page")
    searchText = request.form.get("searchText")
    bookAttr = request.form.get("bookAttr")
    likesearchText = "%" + searchText + "%"

    # Search results fixed to 10 per page

    if bookAttr == "isbn":
        rows = db.execute("SELECT isbn, title, author, year FROM books WHERE isbn LIKE :isbn LIMIT :start OFFSET :off",
                          {"isbn": likesearchText, "start": 10, "off": int(page) * 10}).fetchall()
    elif bookAttr == "title":
        rows = db.execute("SELECT isbn, title, author, year FROM books WHERE title LIKE :title LIMIT :start OFFSET :off",
                          {"title": likesearchText, "start": 10, "off": int(page) * 10}).fetchall()
    else:
        rows = db.execute("SELECT isbn, title, author, year FROM books WHERE author LIKE :author LIMIT :start OFFSET :off",
                          {"author": likesearchText, "start": 10, "off": int(page) * 10}).fetchall()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT isbn, title, author, year
FROM books
WHERE isbn LIKE :isbn OR title LIKE :title OR author LIKE :author;
```

This will work fine if two of the parameters are NULL or empty strings.

Comment: Ah i was thinking along these lines.  So i would have to set title and author and isbn to empty strings and then check which of them the user had selected and then redefine the variable to the searchText and then the query would work right ??  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not actually a SQL solution... but have you considered setting the value column dynamically? Something like this (not tested):

```py
page = request.form.get('page')
searchText = request.form.get('searchText')
bookAttr = request.form.get('bookAttr')
# Avoid SQL injection vulnerability by checking the parameter value
if bookAttr != 'isbn' and bookAttr != 'title' and bookAttr != 'author':
    raise ValueError('Unsupported bookAttr: ' + bookAttr)
rows = db.execute('SELECT isbn, title, author, year FROM books WHERE '
                  + bookAttr
                  + ' LIKE :searchText LIMIT :start OFFSET :off',
                  {'searchText': '%' + searchText + '%', 'start': 10,
                  'off': int(page) * 10}).fetchall()
```